# How can I output HTML in a template without it being passed through a caching filter?

Tags: plugin-w3-total-cache

I'm in a bit of a bind. I'm using W3TC, with the "Prevent caching of objects after settings change" option enabled, so that pagespeed service can be refreshed when needed.

Unfortunately, this adds query strings to everything, including a call to a remote .js file (which is included in one of the template files), which I need to exclude– unfortunately it breaks if there's a query string (which is something that's out of my control to fix).

Is there a way I can just have this bit of HTML be excluded from the W3TC filter somehow? I'm open to calling the page in question with a GET query, but so far can't find a way to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Got it to work:

In wp-config.php I added:

```
define('W3TC_DYNAMIC_SECURITY', 'mysecretcode');
```

I created a PHP file (nocache.php) containing just the HTML to be output, and put it in the root folder. Then in my template file I used:

```
<!-- mclude mysecretcode nocache.php --><!-- /mclude mysecretcode -->
```